# How do I clean vinyl siding without a pressure washer?

Tags: cleaning, vinyl-siding

My vinyl siding is turning green from mildew and I have to clean it up this weekend.

I let a friend borrow my pressure washer at the beginning of the summer, and he's out of the country for awhile.  I'm working that angle to try and get it back.

I called for a rental and found that it's pretty expensive to rent one, even for a few hours.

Are there any products out there that can you can spray on and rinse with a hose?  These stains are 20+ feet up, so I'll bite the bullet on the tool rental before I get up there to scrub.

My dad recommended giving [Jomax](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?storeId=10051&productId=100398378&langId=-1&catalogId=10053&ci_sku=100398378&ci_src=14110944&cm_mmc=shopping-_-googlebase-_-D24X-_-100398378&locStoreNum=4612&marketID=177) a try.  Any experience with this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wouldn't have believed it if I hadn't seen it.  I wish I took before/after pics.

Bought:

Jomax

[image: Jomax]

Clorox Outdoor

[image: Clorox Outdoor]

Put in a garden sprayer designed for bleach according to instructions on Jomax:

- 3/4 cups Jomax
- 2 1/4 cups bleach
- 13 cups water

[image: sprayer]

For 75% of the siding, I applied the mixture, then rinsed after 5 minutes.  A number of sections needed a second application, and the worst section took three.

I rinsed using one of the "fireman" nozzles on my hose, just so I could get it up to the eaves:

[image: nozzles]

I did try just spraying the mildew with the nozzle...worthless.  "Firemen" should sue for defamation.

Anyway, I'm thrilled.  Probably took 25% longer than last year, but I wasn't dripping wet either :)  I'll get a power sprayer for next year, but I'll definitely stick with this; it looks much better than what I get from pressure washing alone.

Comment: just want to add I just used this on my Azek vinyl decking and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Jomax is good. Make sure the area is dry before using it, or you wasted your money. Use a pump sprayer, start at the bottom and work your way up. Let stand for 5 to 10 minutes. Rinse off with a hose or a pressure washer. If you need to reapply, make sure the surface is dry first.

Answer (score 0):

Jomax and bleach worked for me too.  The north side of my taupe siding house was nearly solid green.  I sprayed the mix on, let it sit for about 8 minutes, then worked it horizontally with a long handled car-washing brush and let it sit a few more minutes and rinsed it off with the hose. It's nearly perfect.  I'm going to go over a few sections that were very thick with growth again but from 20 ft you couldn't tell that it wasn't perfect.

One gallon of the mix covered about 10' X 20'

The brush work required a good bit of sweat equity but I think its only required because I let this get so bad.  I'll follow up with a post after I clean the sides that are only dirty (no green stuff growing). I think that spray and rinse will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to a website call Sidingswab.com.  They have a tool that mounts on an extension pole and you order the cleaning pad to fit the profile of your specific siding.  Works great.

Comment: If you are affiliated **in any way** with the product that you linked to, you **must** disclose that. Please see the [expected behavior](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), [product support](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/product-support) and [promotion](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) pages in the [help] for more information.

Comment: I've simply taped a brush onto the end of a long pole and done the same.