# Washing vinyl siding -- hard to reach high up places?

Tags: cleaning, vinyl-siding

There's some spots on my vinyl siding that have gotten dirty. Unfortunately these spots are pretty high up-- about 15-20ft up. What are the best way to clean these spots? Would a power washer aimed up at the siding be a good idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clean vinyl siding without a pressure washer?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1995/clean-vinyl-siding-without-a-pressure-washer)

Answer (score 3):

I use a brush and pole for washing RV's. The pole is a telescoping one usef for painting. I stand on a tall stepladder and the combination can reach pretty high. Lowes had the RV brush. So I spray on some soap, brush, and then rinse.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a power washer with a long handle, however the one I use is a commercial model, and might be more powerful. The only problem is with a pole, the side to side movement won't allow you to apply to much pressure on the head. Plus the over lapped siding won't allow a up and down movement.