# Is clorox outdoor + jomax safe on vinyl decking?

Tags: cleaning, deck

I used the recipe suggested in [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1995/how-do-i-clean-vinyl-siding-without-a-pressure-washer) to successfully clean my vinyl siding. Its a combination of Jomax, Clorox outdoor, and water. I'm wondering if this solution will work fine on my vinyl decking that I'm looking to clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried it on my Azek vinyl decking and it worked great just like it does on vinyl siding. No problems whatsoever.