# Cleaning black spots (putrified insects) off vinyl siding

Tags: vinyl-siding

Is there a clever method to remove the black spots caused by (what I believe to be) putrified mosquitoes and other insects from vinyl siding?  Will [Jomax](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1995/how-do-i-clean-vinyl-siding-without-a-pressure-washer) remove the spots?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Jomax, but a mixture of about 1/2 water and 1/2 vinegar will remove green mildew off vinyl siding very easily.  I have seen the small black spots you mention and have removed them with the same and a little more elbow grease.